# Can't close as duplicate: "An error occurred while searching; please try again"

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, search

I'm trying to close [a question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99768/excluding-google-analytics-spam-by-referral) as a duplicate [of this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-google-analytics-referrer-spammers).   When I enter the URL of the other question into the close question dialog, I get the error:

> An error occurred while searching; please try again

The error occurs when I try to enter a URL into the search box, or when I just click on a question to select it.   The "Vote to Close" box remains greyed out and I can't can't submit.

It looks like this is a bug of some sort.  I've never had this happen to me before.   A similar problem happened on the main meta site in 2013 but it says it was fixed by a release: [Unable to close as duplicate on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198644/unable-to-close-as-duplicate-on-meta)

I've tried in both Firefox and Chrome and I get the same error.  I've tried again several times over about 15 minutes but the problem hasn't gone away.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I found another question that has the same problem when trying to close duplicates: [Why do Google search console and Google analytics show such drastically different data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92546/why-do-google-search-console-and-google-analytics-show-such-drastically-differen)

Answer (score 3):

I found a work around.   The search doesn't like

```
/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-google-analytics-referrer-spammers
```

in the box, but I can remove the URL slug and it will search just fine:

```
/questions/75909/
```

I can also remove any of the following three words from the slug to allow it to go through:

- "google"
- "analytics"
- "referrer"

I'm not sure what it is about the combination of those three words in the slug that causes a problem.  I can search for them using site search just fine.

Comment: Mabye the the q URL shortcut would work as well, like `/q/75909/`